# Add 30 Mins Time to DateTime format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss in AIX 5.0

Tags: ksh, aix

I'm running AIX with coreutils 5.0. I need to advance an arbitrary date (or time) as given conformative to ISO-8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

For example:

Value of `D1` is: `2017-07-08 19:20:01`, and I need to add 30 minutes.

In a modern UNIX-system I could probably write something like

```
date -d "$D1 + 30 minutes" +'%H:%M'
```

but, alas, I need it to work on an old AIX.

Comment: Did you not just ask a similar question earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$ date -d "$(date -d "$D1") + 30 minutes" +'%H:%M'
```

This works in `bash`, but not in `ksh`.

---

The *inner* call to `date` will parse `D1` to a date, and present it in `date`'s "native" format.

```
$ date -d "$D1"
Sat Jul  8 19:20:01 CEST 2017
```

This output will be used with `+ 30 minutes` to create the date that you want, with the *outer* call to date.

The inner call to `date` will be expanded so that

```
$ date -d "$(date -d "$D1") + 30 minutes" +'%H:%M'
```

will be equivalent to

```
$ date -d "Sat Jul  8 19:20:01 CEST 2017 + 30 minutes" +'%H:%M'
```

which will be

```
19:50
```

Comment: I get this error:date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]
Something related to POSIX standards. I'm basically running a KSH file.

Comment: What version of `date` are you using?

Comment: Version Shows AIX,   DATE(1) date (coreutils) 5.0 (March 2003)         DATE(1)

Answer (score 0):

```
date -d @$(($(date -d "$D1" +%s) + 30 * 60)) +%H:%M
```

- `$(date -d "$D1" +%s)` echoes the epoch
- `$((epoch + value))` calculates the wanted time
- `date -d@epoch +fmt` formats it

Comment: explain why this does what the question needs, don't just dump code.

Comment: @jwenting it should be quite obvious, but here we go: $(date -d "$D1" +%s) echoes the epoch, $((epoch + value))  calculates the time he wants, date -d@epoch +fmt formats it.

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution:

```
awk -F '[-: ]' '{
    ram=(mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6)+(30*60));
    print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T",ram) 
}' <<< "$D1"
```

Convert the date to a date string using `awk`'s `mktime` function. Add 30 minutes (30*60) and then convert back to a date string with the required format using strftime.

Comment: If you are just going to concatenate all the fields, isn't it easier to just `gsub` the splitters away?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running AIX from 2003 you are in dire straits, my friend, but if you only need the *time*, not the full date, as your question implies, I think @RamanSailopal got us half way there.

```
echo $D1 | awk -F "[: ]" '{
    m = $3+30;
    h = ($2+int(m/60)) % 24;
    printf("%02i:%02i\n", h, m%60)
}'
```

`awk` splits the input in different fields, with the splitter pattern given in the `-F` argument. The pattern denotes `:` or space .

The input will be split in

```
$1 = 2017-07-08
$2 = 19
$3 = 20
$4 = 01
```

Then the script calculates a fake minute value (that can be more than or equal to 60) and stores it in `m`. From that value it calculates the hour, modulo 24, and the actual minutes, `m` modulo 60.

This could fail if you hit a [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), so if you need second precision at all times, you should use some other method.